Reserve enough space for an inline verb
If \verb|something| happens to be at the end of a line, and the current line does not have enough space to accommodate it, I will get something like this:

\verb|VTextPositionCursor| exceeds the margin.
I wonder if I can define a new command, which will add a new line before \verb|VTextPositionCursor| if the current line does not have enough space for it.

\hfil\nolinebreak[2]\hfilneg\verb|.....| will allow but discourage a linebreak before the verb.

Welcome to TeX.SX!
